# поиск минимального и максимального по критерию длины числа python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана последовательность чисел, завершающаяся числом 0. Найдите самое короткое и длинное число из введенных. Для вычисления длины числа, нахождения минимума и максимума используйте отдельные функции.

**Формат входных данных:**

Вводится последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся числом 0 (само число 0 в последовательность не входит, а служит как признак ее окончания).

```py
def count_digits(num):
    count = 0
    while num:
        num //= 10
        count += 1
    return count
 
def min_max(num, count):
    num_len = count
    max_len, min_len = -1, 99999999
    min_num, max_num = None, None
    if num_len > max_len:
        max_len = num_len
        max_num = num
    if num_len < min_len:
        min_len = num_len
        min_num = num
    print(min_num, max_num)

while True:
    num = int(input())
    if num == 0:
        break
    count = count_digits(num)
    min_max(num, count)
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема, если например просто использовать поиск максимума, т.е убирать в функции часть с посиком минимума, все хорошо.. Не могу понять, где спотыкаюсь...

Comment: по заданию оценить самое длиное и короткое через длину числа, я понимаю, что простое сравнение даст верный результат

Comment: почему не ```max(map(len,'1203405607809'.split('0')))```

Comment: @ganz 

по условию задачни нельзя использовать аткие конструкции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не хватает отступов в двух последних строках, чтобы они входили в тело цикла

Здесь

```
if num_len < max_len:
```

должно быть

```
if num_len < min_len:
```

и min_len инициализируйте большим числом, например, 999999,а не -1

```
def min_max(lst):
    max_len, min_len = -1, 100000
    min_num, max_num = None, None
    for num in lst:
        num_len = count_digits(num)
        if num_len > max_len:
            max_len = num_len
            max_num = num
        if num_len < max_len:
            min_len = max_len
            min_num = num
    return min_num, max_num

lst = []
while True:
    num = int(input())
    if num == 0:
        break
    else:
        lst.append(num)
print(min_max(lst))
```

Comment: я если посление две строки внесу в цикл, то буду получать вывод:
79
None 79
198
None 198

Comment: min_len =  -1 нехорошо. Кроме того, max_len, min_len у вас локальные переменные, они не сохраняются между вызовами.

Comment: теперь просто вывод двух максимальных чисел, исправил код

Comment: смотрите рабочий код. я полагаю, более продвинутые средства питона использовать нельзя? (max на list c функцией сравнения)

Comment: теперь работает, осталось только мне преобразовать кортеж в строку, чтобы вывести в виде строки и в принципе все! А так да, по условию, нельзя использовать встроенные средства